# Catch and handle PayPal SDK HTTP Exceptions PHP yii2

Tags: php, paypal, sdk

i've been working with the Paypal SDK and i have an action that verifies 
the order of the payment made.

I want to catch and handle the Paypal Errors during the transaction to later show it on a message.

i tried adding PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException on catch without any result.

this how it shows the error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlRge.png

My code action:

```
public static function actionGetorder($orderId)
{
    try 
    {
        // 3. Call PayPal to get the transaction details
        $client = PayPalClient::client();
        $response = $client->execute(new OrdersGetRequest($orderId)); //The order ID isn't valid so it will give the error

        var_dump ($response->result->payer->email_address);
        print "Status: {$response->result->status}\n";
    } 
    catch (PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $ex) 
    {
        echo "lol";
    }

}
```

The idea is in that code it should show the lol message but it doesn't, so is it possible catch and handle the error and how?.

Thanks for reading, greetings.

Comment: I guess you just using a wrong exception. `..ConnectionException` i think respond to a connection failure or wrong credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exceptions can be different. But in your code, you're only trying to catch up a single exception which is `PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException`. But what if the exception is other one? Obviously PHP execution flow will then not go to your catch block thus you don't see the message `lol`. In your image shows that your code catches `PayPalHttp\HttpException`.

So you need to try to set up multiple `catch` blocks. That means you can add as many exceptions as you need like the code below:

```
public static function actionGetorder($orderId)
{
    try {
        // 3. Call PayPal to get the transaction details
        $client = PayPalClient::client();
        $response = $client->execute(new OrdersGetRequest($orderId)); //The order ID isn't valid so it will give the error

        var_dump ($response->result->payer->email_address);
        print "Status: {$response->result->status}\n";
    } catch (PayPalHttp\HttpException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    } catch (PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    } finally {
        echo 'If no exception has already been caught, show your own custom message';
    }
}
```

Now the question is how do you know which exceptions you should use? Well, it can be known from the code you're using inside `try {}` block.

In you case, check out whether `PayPalClient::client(); or`$client->execute(new OrdersGetRequest($orderId)); raises any exception. If they do, use them in the `catch` block.

Hope this would help you!

Comment: Thanks for answer but it doesnt catching any of those, im looking the PayPalHttp\HttpClient.php and it looks like it have his own exception, at the trace image you can see the code

Comment: I think you didn't get me. You have to find out those exceptions are being used in the `try {}` block and set them one by one to the `catch` block. And FYI `try-catch` block is used so that your script doesn't stop if any exception raised somewhere in your code. Thanks

Comment: yeah i understand perfectly but im trying to say seems like i cant catch any exception because the PaypalClient.php have this line on the code: throw new HttpException($body, $statusCode, $headers); If I am not mistaken, it is not returning any value, it is automatically throwing an exception to the server. Greetings

Comment: Solved: 
I had an error with the classes routem thanks so much for your help <3.

Comment: I'm glad that you solved the problem. Happy Coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

I had a route problem to the classes, so this is how the code works on yii2, I hope it helps someone:

```
try 
    {
        // $orderId = base64_decode($orderId);
        $client = PayPalClient::client();
        $response = $client->execute(new OrdersGetRequest($orderId));
        $status = $response->result->status;
        $email_cliente = $response->result->payer->email_address;

        if ($status != 'COMPLETED') 
        {
            \Yii::$app->session->setFlash('error', \Yii::t("app", "problema_pago"));

            return $this->redirect(['../web/pagar']);
        }


    }
    catch (\PayPalHttp\HttpException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    } catch (\PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
```